# AngularJS Display 1 Post in New Page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display only `Test Post 1` in next html page `titleDetails.html` when user clicks `Test Post 1` in `index.html`

**1) titleDetails() in index.html**:

```
<a ng-click="titleDetails(post)">{{ post.title }} </a>
```

**2) controller variables and titleDetails() method:**

```
function BlogController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location) {
    $scope.createPost = createPost;
    $scope.deletePost = deletePost;
    $scope.editPost = editPost;
    $scope.updatePost = updatePost;
    $scope.titleDetails = titleDetails;
    $scope.postDetail = null;

function titleDetails(post)
{ 
    $scope.postDetail = post; 
    $location.path('#/titleDetails'); 
}
```

**3) body in titleDetails.html:**

```
<body> 
    <div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController">
        <h1>Blog</h1>
            <div>
                <h2>
                    <a>{{ postDetail.title }} </a>
                </h2>
                    <em>{{postDetail.posted}}</em>
                    <p>{{postDetail.body}}</p>
            </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

---

**FULL CODE:**

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    angular
    .module("BlogApp", [])
    .controller("BlogController", BlogController);

    function BlogController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location) {
        $scope.createPost = createPost;
        $scope.deletePost = deletePost;
        $scope.editPost = editPost;
        $scope.updatePost = updatePost;
        $scope.titleDetails = titleDetails;
        $scope.postDetail = null;

    function init() {
        getAllPosts();
    }
    init();

    function titleDetails(post)
    { 
        $scope.postDetail = post; 
        $location.path('#/titleDetails'); 
    }

    function updatePost(post){
        console.log(post);
        $http
        .put("/api/blogpost/"+post._id, post)
        .success(getAllPosts);
    }

    function editPost(postId){
        $http
        .get("/api/blogpost/"+postId)
        .success(function(post){
            $scope.post = post;
        });
    }

        function deletePost(postId){
            $http
            .delete("/api/blogpost/"+postId)
            .success(getAllPosts);
        }

        function getAllPosts(){
            $http
            .get("/api/blogpost")
            .success(function(posts) {
                $scope.posts = posts;
            });
        }

        function createPost(post) {
            console.log(post);
            $http
            .post("/api/blogpost",post)
            .success(getAllPosts);
        }
    }
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="BlogApp">
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController">
        <h1>Blog</h1>
            <input ng-model="post.title" class="form-control" placeholder="title"/>
            <textarea ng-model="post.body" class="form-control" placeholder="body"></textarea>
            <button ng-click="createPost(post)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Post</button>
            <button ng-click="updatePost(post)" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Update</button>

            <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
                <h2>
                    <a ng-click="titleDetails(post)">{{ post.title }} </a>
                    <a ng-click="editPost(post._id)" class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <a ng-click="deletePost(post._id)" class="pull-right"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                </h2>
                <em>{{post.posted}}</em>
                <p>{{post.body}}</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**titleDetails.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="BlogApp">
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController">
        <h1>Blog</h1>
            <div>
                <h2>
                    <a>{{ postDetail.title }} </a>
                </h2>
                    <em>{{postDetail.posted}}</em>
                    <p>{{postDetail.body}}</p>
            </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: pass post object in titleDetails() like titleDetails(post). no need to use ng-repeater in titleDetails.html if you want to show only single post

Comment: What does the titleDetails() function do? Is there routing involved?

Comment: titleDetails() gets the title id from index.html and parses it to titleDetails in the next page. i am unsure if I am doing it correctly. @YogeshPatil

Comment: i have also edited my titleDetails, removing ng-repeat @Jigarb1992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this following steps work for you
Pass **post** object to `titleDetail()` function. 

In **index.html**

```
<a  ng-click="titleDetails(post)">{{ post.title }} </a>
```

In function assign post to $rootScope variable

```
$scope.titleDetails = function(post) {
   $rootScope.postDetail = post;
}
```

Now your **titleDetail.html** page controller:

```
$scope.post = $rootScope.postDetail;
```

Comment: the error in development console shows the error: angular.min.js:117 ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined

Comment: you have to inject the $rootScope in your controller function. Like function BlogController($scope, $http, $rootScope)

Answer (score 1):

a new scope variable in BlogController

```
$scope.postDetail = null;
```

and method titleDetails() be like

```
$scope.titleDetails = function(post) {
$scope.postDetail = post;
}
```

and also make change in index.html

```
 <a  ng-click="titleDetails(post)">{{ post.title }} </a>
```

Comment: My current function in my app.js (controller) is as such: function titleDetails(postId){
   window.location = "/titleDetails.html";
 }

That links me to titleDetails.html. Do I change it to your method titleDetails()?

Comment: keep you function as this   function titleDetails(post){ $scope.postDetail = post; window.location = "/titleDetails.html"; } and when calling this function from index.html send "post" as parameter not "postId"

Comment: I have put the methods and variables in my controller app.js, and index.html. However, my next html page still display as blank. I have edited my thread as well. Thank you

Comment: thanks for updating your thread.
you need you make some changes in your titleDetails.html as follow
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController">
        <h1>Blog</h1>
            <div>
                <h2>
                <a>{{ postDetail.title }} </a>
                </h2>
                <em>{{postDetail.posted}}</em>
                <p>{{postDetail.body}}</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>

Comment: thank you for the advice. I have changed the code in my titleDetails.html as follows and edited my thread. However, my titleDetails.html page still displays empty when I click on 1 post in my main index.html. Thank you

Comment: okay here is some angular thing. You are currently using window.location="titleDetails.html"; this is something out of angular js, and when you use something out of angularjs in controller, the digest cycle doesn't fires when scope variables are modified. So you can try replacing window.location by angular's $location factory or explicitly revoke the digest cycle by using $scope.$apply(); in titleDetails function. Hope it will work now.

Comment: I have edited my code, and applied $scope.$apply(); in titleDetails function. However, nothing happens when I click on the title now. Sorry for the trouble and thank you

Comment: Ah sorry, i didn't get it earlier, actually titleDetails.html is initiating its own scope of BlogController controller, so any value of the previous scope wont be available in this page. you can change $scope.postDetail to $rootScope.postDetail and inject $rootScope in controller.

Comment: I will also suggest you to use ui-routes in your app. and use different states for different pages, and you can share data between states easily.