# AngularJS $location directory

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Main page URL: http://localhost:3000/

Current second page URL: http://localhost:3000/#/titleDetails.html

Expected second page URL: http://localhost:3000/titleDetails.html

Currently when I click on the title in my main page, the URL contains an extra `/#` which causes the page to be redirected to `titleDetails.html`.

The directory of `titleDetails.html` and `index.html` is in the same directory.

May I know how can I fix this?

[Original Post: AngularJS Display 1 Post in New Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809506/angularjs-display-1-post-in-new-page/42812596?noredirect=1#comment72831313_42812596)

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    angular
    .module("BlogApp", [])
    .config(function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    })
    .controller("BlogController", BlogController);

    function BlogController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location) {
        $scope.createPost = createPost;
        $scope.deletePost = deletePost;
        $scope.editPost = editPost;
        $scope.updatePost = updatePost;
        $scope.titleDetails = titleDetails;
        $scope.postDetail = null;

    function init() {
        getAllPosts();
    }
    init();

    function titleDetails(post)
    { 
        $scope.postDetail = post; 
        $location.path('/titleDetails.html'); 
    }

    function updatePost(post){
        console.log(post);
        $http
        .put("/api/blogpost/"+post._id, post)
        .success(getAllPosts);
    }

    function editPost(postId){
        $http
        .get("/api/blogpost/"+postId)
        .success(function(post){
            $scope.post = post;
        });
    }

        function deletePost(postId){
            $http
            .delete("/api/blogpost/"+postId)
            .success(getAllPosts);
        }

        function getAllPosts(){
            $http
            .get("/api/blogpost")
            .success(function(posts) {
                $scope.posts = posts;
            });
        }

        function createPost(post) {
            console.log(post);
            $http
            .post("/api/blogpost",post)
            .success(getAllPosts);
        }
    }
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="BlogApp">
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController">
        <h1>Blog</h1>
            <input ng-model="post.title" class="form-control" placeholder="title"/>
            <textarea ng-model="post.body" class="form-control" placeholder="body"></textarea>
            <button ng-click="createPost(post)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Post</button>
            <button ng-click="updatePost(post)" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Update</button>

            <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
                <h2>
                    <a ng-click="titleDetails(post)">{{ post.title }} </a>
                    <a ng-click="editPost(post._id)" class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <a ng-click="deletePost(post._id)" class="pull-right"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                </h2>
                <em>{{post.posted}}</em>
                <p>{{post.body}}</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**titleDetails.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="BlogApp">
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController">
        <h1>Blog</h1>
            <div>
                <h2>
                    <a>{{ postDetail.title }} </a>
                </h2>
                    <em>{{postDetail.posted}}</em>
                    <p>{{postDetail.body}}</p>
            </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Console Error in index.html:**

```
angular.js:13708 Error: [$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$location/nobase
    at angular.js:38
    at sf.$get (angular.js:13384)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4709)
    at angular.js:4508
    at d (angular.js:4655)
    at e (angular.js:4679)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4701)
    at R.instance (angular.js:10234)
    at m (angular.js:9147)
    at g (angular.js:8510)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular has 3 routing operates:

- Hashbang Mode
- HTML5 Mode
- Hashbang in HTML5 Mode

You can configure: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');`

Check [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Comment: after I put the configuration in my controller variables, my page stop loading any posts

Comment: you need add this to  angular `config`, not in `controller`. Something like this: `.config(function($locationProvider) {}`

Comment: May I know where can I find the angular `config` file? or is it the top part of the code in my `app.js`?

Comment: yes, define to in app.js, here `angular
    .module("BlogApp", []).config(function($locationProvider) {//code here})`

Comment: i have inserted the code as instructed, however, on my webpage now, it displays the title, body, posted and comments as `{{ post.title }}`, `{{post.posted}}` and `{{post.body}}`, and only 1 of it is displayed.

Comment: Are some errors in browser console? And on which page titleDetails.html?

Comment: You are missing `)` in`config` definition, before `controller`

Comment: thank you. i have fixed the `)` error in `config` definition. however another error appears. i have edited my thread and the error shown. appreciate it

Comment: add `<base href="/" />` in your head section

Comment: thank you @NikhilBhandari and @MatejMarconak. This solved the `$location` issue. However I am seeing empty result in my new page. I will post it as a new question. Thank you.